# Phantom Spacing between <img> and a div

Tags: css, image, spacing

I have an `<img>` sitting next to a inline block div, which I believe is causing the problem, but setting the `<img>` to display:block breaks the design

Here is the html:

---

```
            <img src="./images/Portrait2.jpg">

            <div id="AboutText">
                <h3>ZUG ZUG, ME NOT THAT TYPE OF ORC</h3>
                <p>
                    Me Andrew Benson, I make pretty thing you see. It make people want buy thing, make you happy. Me understand basic color theory. Color make people feel thing, yes? Blue make calm, yellow DANGER, red make go faster DAKA DAKA. But that work, me not work all time, me normal have hobbies. Me like making plant grow big and keepin fishies. If me not doing that and you have read through resume contact me with a email. It easy stupid head. (PLACEHOLDER TEXT)
                </p>


               <section class="AboutLists Margin">
                    <h3>FORTE</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Branding</li>
                        <li>Illustration</li>
                        <li>Web Design</li>
                        <li>Packaging</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="AboutLists Margin">
                    <h3>FEATURED</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>The Dieline</li>
                        <li>Packaging of the World</li>
                        <li>Scholastic Awards</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="AboutLists">
                    <h3>OTHER MEDIUMS</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.behance.net/AndrewJBenson" target="_new">Behance</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://dribbble.com/BensonbyDesign" target="_new">Dribble</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Public Profilehttps://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-benson-b209b769" target="_new">Linkden</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/BensonbyDesign" target="_new">Twitter</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the affected css:

```
hr{
border: 2px solid rgba(190,190,190,1.00);

margin-bottom: 15vh;
margin-top: 10vh;
margin-left:2%; 
margin-right:2%;
}

#AboutText hr{
text-align: left;
width: 10%;
}

#About{
overflow: hidden;
margin-left:2%; 
margin-right:2%;
clear: both;

margin-bottom: 160px;
}

#About img{
width:30%;
height: auto;
vertical-align: top;
}

#AboutText{
width: 60%;
display: inline-block;
}

#AboutText h3{
font-family: 'Lato', serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11pt;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color:rgba(190,190,190,1.00);

margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#About p{
line-height: 30px;
font-family: 'Lato', serif;
font-weight: thin;
color:rgba(80,80,80,1.00);

margin-bottom: 135px;
}

.AboutLists{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}


.AboutLists.Margin{
margin-right: 10%;
}

.AboutLists h3{
font-family: 'Lato', serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11pt;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color:rgba(190,190,190,1.00);

margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.AboutLists li{
line-height: 30px;
font-family: 'Lato', serif;
font-weight: thin;
color:rgba(80,80,80,1.00);

text-decoration: none;
}

.AboutLists a{
color:rgba(80,80,80,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have a live version on my test page here in the about section: http://benson.graphics/test/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left` to `#About img`, this will make that space disappear.

Comment: That works, I had floated it earlier, but on advice from another user I thought the float was unneeded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The space is caused by the inline-block element.  There are a few ways around this but the simplest is to set the containers font size to 0.  So in this case it would be:

```
#About{
 font-size:0;
}
```

You will then need to specify font sizes for the text elements in this section.